# Disabling a button on form.submit causes it is skipped in the posted data

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code on a page which finds every submit button on the page, find the form it is located in and adds a listener which disables the button for few seconds so it prevents accidental duplicated submit of the form.

```
<input type="submit" id="submitForm" name="submitForm" value="Click me"/>

form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
    button.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        button.disabled = false;
    }, 5000);
});
```

However, disabling the button causes that `submitForm=Click me` parameter is not sent to the server.

How to achieve on the client side that the user cannot accidentally click the button (or press Enter key) twice but the browser still sends which button causes the form submit?

Comment: One option might be to make it `.disabled` in an immediate `setTimeout`, but I wonder if there's a more elegant way

Comment: `submitForm=Submit me` will not be sent because the `submit` event only sends values from `input`, `textarea`, and `selects`. A `type="submit/reset/button"`` value  nor a `<button>` tag will be sent as actual data. If you want static data to be sent try `<input type='hidden'>`.

Comment: @zer00ne There must be some misunderstanding as the backend code rely on sending that information by browsers for many, many years.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I wonder as well as setting a immediate timeout means that the button can be pressed again before the timeout is processed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a variable to indicate that the form is submitting and so would exit if it has already been submitted

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form class="form form_1">
            <input type="submit" class="form-button" name="submitForm" value="Submit me" />
        </form>

        <form class="form form_3">
            <input type="submit" class="form-button" name="submitForm" value="Submit me" />
        </form>

        <form class="form form_3">
            <input type="submit" class="form-button" name="submitForm" value="Submit me" />
        </form>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
        var isSubmitting = false;

        forms.forEach(function(form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                // This simply prevents the form from doing anything shady
                event.preventDefault();

                if (isSubmitting) {
                    return;
                }

                isSubmitting = true;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    isSubmitting = false;
                }, 5000);

                // Other code here
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

There are other approaches which could achieve the same results, such as implementing an observer/pub-sub, using jQuery to simplify the loop and using React and maintaining state

Comment: The button disabling code is a generic code altering all forms. These forms are unaware of this prevention and some of them has their custom handlers as well.

Comment: If I understand you properly, are you looking to disable all forms and reactivate them after 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to prevent all forms to be submitted in 5 seconds following their last submit (just to prevent accidental duplicated submits like clicking twice on the button instead of once).

Comment: In that case, I'm editting my answer to reflect a solution

Comment: Thanks for editing. However, I do not see how to make the disabling code a standalone code and transparent from the perspective of the existing forms code.

Answer (score 0):

As @zer00ne wrote - you should add a hidden field instead of using the button for sending values:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="submitForm" name="submitForm" value="Click me" />
<input type="submit" value="Click me" />
```

Comment: I do not use buttons to send values. I use it to determine which button was clicked on. That's a standard HTML feature since an ice age.

Comment: In that case, I might try a css/html hack: `button.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; button.tabIndex = -1;`

Answer (score 0):

## Since the Beginning of Time

> *"A button (and its value) is only included in the form submission if the button itself was used to initiate the form submission."*

[<sup>Second *"Note"*</sup>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type-submit-state#the-button-element)

Indeed OP is correct and I am mistaken.

---

### Solutions

#### Demo 1

**Synchronous Operation**

An asynchronous task like submitting a form needs to be managed by **[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** if timing and order of behavior needs to been done synchronously. By using [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) we can can ensure that tasks can be done one at a time and in a predetermined order.

---

#### Demo 2

**Asynchronous Operation**

Both timeout functions fire one after another but because they are asynchronous, there's no guarantee that at 5 sec the second function will be resolved should there be other tasks that are prioritized before it. If disabling buttons is the only task that you'll have then **Demo 2** is sufficient.

---

### Demo 1

**Details commented in demo**
**Demo is using a live test server. The `<iframe>` shows the response when 200.**

```js
// Declare async function -- pass the Event Object
async function isolateSubmit(e) {

  // Reference the tag registered to event (the selected <form>)
  const node = e.currentTarget;

  // Reference the form's submit button by its [name]
  const btn = node.elements.submit;

  /* 
  Wrap the expression: btn.disabled = true 
  within a Promise that starts immediately 
  (actually delayed @1.7ms)
  */
  function remClick() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(btn.disabled = true)
      }, 0);
    });
  }

  /* 
  Wrap the assignment: btn.disabled = false 
  within a Promise that starts after 5s. 
  */
  function addClick() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(btn.disabled = false)
      }, 5000);
    });
  }

  /*
  -- performance.now() are timestamps in ms see console
  -- When the keyword "await" is added before each Promise 
     they are resolved one after another -- synchronously
  */
  let t0 = performance.now();
  await remClick();
  let t1 = performance.now();
  await addClick();
  let t2 = performance.now();

  console.log(`remClick: ${t1 - t0}`);
  console.log(`addClick: ${t2 - t1}`);
}

// Collect all <form>s into a HTMLCollection and convert that into an array
const forms = Array.from(document.forms);

/*
-- Run new array through .forEach() method.
-- On each iteration:
  -- Register the current <form> to the submit event. 
     Pass isolateSubmit() as the callback.
  -- {Optional} Assign a unique #id to each <form>.
*/
forms.forEach((node, idx) => {
  node.addEventListener('submit', isolateSubmit);
  node.id = 'f' + (idx + 1);
  console.log(`Listener for submit event has been added to form#${node.id}.`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  display: none;
}

form {
  width: 48%;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px dashed red
}

.hint {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 0.75rem
}
```

```html
<form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
  <input>
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Form 1'>
</form>

<form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
  <input>
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Form 2'>
</form>

<form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
  <input>
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Form 3'>
</form>

<p class='hint'>Look for the "submit" property of "form" Object -- the value should follow this pattern: "Form [1-3]"</p>

<iframe name='response' width='50%'></iframe>
```

---

### Demo 2

**This demo is a non-Promise version**
**Demo is using a live test server. The `<iframe>` shows the response when 200.**

```js
// Declare callback function -- pass the Event Object
function isolateSubmit(e) {

  // Reference the tag registered to event (the selected <form>)
  const node = e.currentTarget;

  // Reference the form's submit button by its [name]
  const btn = node.elements.submit;

  /* 
  btn.disabled = true 
  starts immediately 
  */
  const remClick = setTimeout(function() {
    btn.disabled = true
  }, 0);

  /* 
  btn.disabled = false 
  Supposed to start after 5s. 
  But is asynchronous see console 
  */
  const addClick = setTimeout(function() {
    btn.disabled = false
  }, 5000);
  /*
  -- performance.now() are timestamps in ms see console
  -- Both timeout functions fire one after another but 
     because they are asynchronous, there's no guarantee that
     at 5s addClick will be resolved should there be other
     tasks that are prioritized before it. If this is the only
     tasks that you'll have then this is sufficient.
  */
  let t0 = performance.now();
  remClick;
  let t1 = performance.now();
  addClick;
  let t2 = performance.now();

  console.log(`remClick: ${t1 - t0}`);
  console.log(`addClick: ${t2 - t1}`);

}
// Collect all <form>s into a HTMLCollection and convert that into an array
const forms = Array.from(document.forms);

/*
-- Run new array through .forEach() method.
-- On each iteration:
  -- Register the current <form> to the submit event. 
     Pass isolateSubmit() as the callback.
  -- {Optional} Assign a unique #id to each <form>.
*/
forms.forEach((node, idx) => {
  node.addEventListener('submit', isolateSubmit);
  node.id = 'f' + (idx + 1);
  console.log(`Listener for submit event has been added to form#${node.id}.`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.as-console-row.as-console-row::after {
  display: none;
}

form {
  width: 48%;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 1px dashed red
}

.hint {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 0.75rem
}
```

```html
<form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
  <input>
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Form 1'>
</form>

<form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
  <input>
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Form 2'>
</form>

<form action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post' target='response'>
  <input>
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Form 3'>
</form>

<p class='hint'>Look for the "submit" property of "form" Object -- the value should follow this pattern: "Form [1-3]"</p>

<iframe name='response' width='50%'></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am just a little bit lost in the added benefit on top of just calling `setTimeout` without using promises.
`setTimeout(function () { button.disabled = true; }, 0); setTimeout(function () { button.disabled = false; }, 5000);`